# Access not throwing error if duplicate records are inserted into table

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm using the following code to import a Excel spreadsheet into a access Database:

```vb
Dim appAccess As Access.Application
Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "path_to_db"
appAccess.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "my_db_table_name", "path_to_excel_file", hasFieldNames, acImportRange
```

The first Column in my Database is the Primary-Key.
I don't get any errors, if data with the same Primary-Keys are inserted. I would like to get errors however.
How can I force an error if duplicate rows are contained in the spreadsheet?

Comment: Add a unique index on the field holding your primary key in the Access table.

Comment: @Gustav If I look into the Table properties, there is already an Index (I guess when I set the Primary Key this is created automatically) which is unique...

Comment: Then records must have and will have unique values in this field.

Comment: @Gustav They do have unique value. The duplicates just simply don't get inserted... That's not a behavior I would expect/want.

Comment: Then you must inspect the records before you insert them in the final table. Write to a temp table, for example, and check this for dupes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the convenience method, TransferSpreadsheet, consider using a direct SQL query to Excel workbook (which is allowable in Access SQL) to capture the exception error as shown below. Because MS Access is both a GUI application and database engine, you would need to enable two different references. Adjust below SQL statement with actual columns, names, and paths.

```vb
Public Sub CaptureExceptions()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database                   ' ENABLE Microsoft Office x.x Access database engine object library
    Dim appAccess As Access.Application      ' ENABLE Microsoft Access x.x Object Library

    Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

    appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Path\To\Access\Database.accdb"

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO my_db_table_name (Col1, Col2, Col3, ...)" _
              & " SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, ..." _
              & " FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR = Yes;Database=C:\Path\To\Excel\Workbook.xlsx].[SheetName$];"

    Set db = appAccess.CurrentDb()
    db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

    appAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase

ExitHandle:
    Set db = Nothing: Set appAccess = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "RUNTIME ERROR"
    Resume ExitHandle
End Sub
```

[image: Exception Message]